# How to reduce file size of PySpark output to that of Hive?

Tags: pyspark, hive, google-cloud-storage, orc, snappy

I am writing orc snappy files to a Google Cloud Storage Bucket using PySpark and Hive. Hive produces a single file output that is significantly smaller than the output produced by Hive. How can I make PySpark produce an output the size that Hive does?

Here is an example output of two identical queries I ran to produce the exact same file in GCS, one with Hive and the other with PySpark.

[Hive output of 72.9 MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLJL8.png)

[PySpark output totaling 86.4 MB across 9 parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2kPs.png)

Edit: Here are the codes I've been using:

To create the Hive table based on a csv file with 15 million rows and 6 columns of random integers.

```
    drop table if exists dummy_data;
    create external table if not exists dummy_data (
    column1 int,
    column2 int,
    column3 int,
    column4 int,
    column5 int,
    column6 int)
    row format delimited
    fields terminated by ','
    stored as textfile
    location 'gs://dummy_bucket_mlw/dummy_data/'
    tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

To create a GCS table that I will load data from the dummy_data table into using Hive.

```
    drop table if exists hive_test_table;
    create external table if not exists hive_test_table (
    column1 int,
    column2 int,
    column3 int,
    column4 int,
    column5 int,
    column6 int)
    stored as orc
    location 'gs://dummy_bucket_mlw/hive_test_table'
    tblproperties ('ORC.COMPRESS' = 'SNAPPY');
```

Load data into table from dummy_data table via Hive:

```
    INSERT INTO hive_test_table
    SELECT *
    FROM dummy_data;
```

[Results in this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLJL8.png)

Create a table in Hive to load data into it using PySpark:

```
    drop table if exists pyspark_test_table;
    create external table if not exists hive_test_table (
    column1 int,
    column2 int,
    column3 int,
    column4 int,
    column5 int,
    column6 int)
    stored as orc
    location 'gs://dummy_bucket_mlw/hive_test_table'
    tblproperties ('ORC.COMPRESS' = 'SNAPPY');
```

Updated PySpark code that combines all file parts into one, but does not compress it to that of the Hive method:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
xr = client.get_bucket("dummy_bucket_mlw")

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("pyspark_test_load") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", 'nonstrict')
spark.conf.set("hive.server2.builtin.udf.blacklist", "emply_bl")

# Execute the query to retrieve the data
my_query = """
    SELECT * FROM dummy_data
"""
df = spark.sql(my_query)

# Compress the data and insert into the existing Hive table
output_table = "pyspark_test_table"

# Configure compression and insert the data into the Hive table
df.repartition(1).write.format("orc").mode("append").option("compression", "snappy").insertInto(output_table)
```

[Results in this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3x8c.png)

Answer (score 0):

At the end when you are writing to table, use `repartition(1)`.

**`Example:`**

```
dataframe.repartition(1)...
```

Comment: this combines all of the files into a single output, but the output size is (86.3 MB) is still larger than Hive's (72.9 MB). Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: could you share the sample code from spark and hive?

Comment: sure, I've updated the question to include the codes I've been using.